Error with CORS in project with Angular and Laravel
I'm working on a web project where I'm using Angular and Laravel. I managed to create a registration form successfully, thus creating users and solving the CORS issue. Now I'm facing a similar problem with the Login part. It's not working properly as it's giving me a CORS error again only in login, not in the registration form. Here's how my files are configured:
UserController:
public function store(Request $request){

$credentials = $request->only('email','password');

if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->filled('remember'))) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->intended('/');
}
return back()->withErrors([
    'email' => 'The provided credentials do not match our records.',
]);

}
api.php:
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/users/store', [UserController::class, 'store']);

Cors.php:
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): 
(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
    return $response;
}

}
And this is my service from Angular:
loginUser(userData: any): Observable<any>{
const requestOptions = {
    withCredentials: true
};
return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/users/store', userData, requestOptions);

}

And the error message when I press the button for login:


Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/store' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute. message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/users/store: 0 Unknown Error" POST http://localhost:8000/api/users/store net::ERR_FAILED


For first, laravel include cors functionality: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/routing#cors

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards

Add this to your Cors.php:
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');



I've added it and it still doesn't work for me.

@starnix do you get any other error after adding it?

same error, I am making the routes in Angular, not in web.php, it won't have anything to do with that, right?

I managed to solve the error. As I mentioned, it was working fine in the registration process but not in the login. There was a conflict in Laravel because the framework itself creates a file cors.php, and then I created another Cors.php, which is the one I shared in my question. It seems the only thing I had to do was to comment out everything inside the one created by Laravel by default (cors.php) and modify the one I created, leaving it like this so that it picks up requests coming from Angular:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class Cors
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): 
(\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
{
    $response = $next($request);

    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD');
    $response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Application');
    return $response;
}
}


If anyone else is experiencing this issue with laravel 11 and Angular, first run
php artisan config:publish cors, which will generate a cors.php file in the config folder, then make sure the following settings are adjusted
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:4200'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,


this fixed my problem , but i dont understand why it should be explicit ?
when i tried 'allowed_origins' => [*], it faild!
